# Monogame performance issues on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xna, monogame

My friends and I are developing a game for Ipad/Iphone using the monogame Framework. We are at the final stage of the development and we are having some issues concerning the deploy of the game.

This is our first IOS game and we really need help to make this game happen.

This is our website: http://www.dumativa.com.br/index.php/pt-BR/projetos/dragon-festival (This isn't the newest version of the game but you can see what it looks like)

Since this is our first game we kinda made some mistakes we are trying to fix. Our textures were made focusing the ipad size (1024x768). We don't really know if that was the right aproach. We thought it would be better to scale them down to iphone instead of the other way around.

We need help with the following topics:

1 - The PVRTC compression.

1.1 - Is it really necessary to implement this in order to improve the game performance?

1.2 - How does transparency works with these compressed textures? We have some textures that have a transparency gradient and we wonder how is it going to look after compression.

1.3 - Do you recomend us to remake all the textures to texture atlas using "power of 2" in order to make the PVRTC compression work?

2 - ARMv7

2.1 - How does it helps to improve the game performance?

2.2 - How do we make sure that it is working after I enabled it in monodevelop?

3 - Texture Size/Resolution

3.1 - Are we right about the scaling or should we develop textures for iphone resolution and then scale them up to ipad?

3.2 - Should we have two different apps (one for iphone and one for ipad) with the same textures but with different sizes for each device?

4 - Sugestions

Do you have any sugestion or point that we are missing? We don't really know how to improve further then the topics listed above. We need every possible direction.

Basically we need to decide which way we need to go to improve our performance and playing experience. We would really apreciate your help and you wont regret once this game is launched :)!

Thank you very much.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to profile your game to see where the problems are.  Is it a GPU or a CPU problem?  You could waste quite a bit of time optimizing the wrong area without profiling first.

Comment: I should have mentioned, we did profile it, using Visual Studio Pro's built-in profiler, and we did eliminate quite a few problems (most were related to Garbage Collection issues due to excessive string instances being generated), but thanks anyway.

Comment: I believe ARMv7 ensures that the device supports floating point calculations which is particularly important if you are using a physics engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to most of your questions is going to be "it depends". There is no substitute for testing on an actual target device and seeing if it's acceptable or not.

I have two general suggestions: (a) make sure you have as few textures/spritesheets as possible, ideally one per scene for a 2D game. And (b) yes, I would create resized/resampled graphics for different target devices instead of relying on dynamic scaling. This is very important for non-Retina hardware like the iPad mini, where it is a terrible idea to load huge images unnecessarily. Better to have a slightly larger download up front followed by an optimal playing experience.

Comment: I see! Thanks very much for your input, we'll try doing that and see if the performance gain is significant. We were using individual images for each asset in the game, as we did not know it could cause performance loss, so that should really improve our situation.

Comment: I have my own project with MonoGame going, where I'm concurrently developing my own game engine. I use Inkscape for all my graphics, and it's integrated with my engine such that it will build optimized spritesheets including all the images I use on a particular scene, at the optimum size, along with metadata like rectangles etc. (I guess it's not all Inkscape, because I also integrated with BmFont. Oh, and another suggestion which I got from the author of DrawAStickMan -- use binary serialization. I use JSON for design time and my own binary serialization for runtime. Good luck!